# Simple jQuery conflict

Tags: jquery

I am (very) new to jQuery so please be gentle but I cannot seem to get the basic script below to work properly.

The immediate class when loaded is .menuFlyout and when it's clicked it changes as needed however the second part to change it back does not work. noConflict() doesn't help.

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.menuFlyout').click(function(){
        jQuery('.menuFlyout').addClass('closeFlyout');
        jQuery('.menuFlyout').removeClass('menuFlyout');
    });
    jQuery('.closeFlyout').click(function(){
        jQuery('.closeFlyout').addClass('menuFlyout');
        jQuery('.closeFlyout').removeClass('closeFlyout');
    });
});
```

Comment: wouldn't toggling the classes be better so you would only have one event handler?

Comment: Also method chaining:  `jQuery('.menuFlyout').addClass('closeFlyout').removeClass('menuFlyout');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(document).on('click','.menuFlyout', function(){
        jQuery('.menuFlyout').addClass('closeFlyout');
        jQuery('.menuFlyout').removeClass('menuFlyout');
    });
    jQuery(document).on('click','.closeFlyout', function(){
        jQuery('.closeFlyout').addClass('menuFlyout');
        jQuery('.closeFlyout').removeClass('closeFlyout');
    });
});
```

The problem with your code is that there is no element with class `closeFlyout` when you attah the handler. You need to delegate the click handler using [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method (see section "Direct and delegated events" for more details ).

Using event delegation should fix your problem but as a side note here you have 2 improved versions of your code (as sugggested by @wirey and @h0tw1r3)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(document).on('click','.menuFlyout', function(){
        jQuery(this).addClass('closeFlyout').removeClass('menuFlyout');
    });
    jQuery(document).on('click','.closeFlyout', function(){
        jQuery(this).addClass('menuFlyout').removeClass('closeFlyout')
    });
});
```

or

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(document).on('click','.menuFlyout, .closeFlyout', function(){
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('closeFlyout');
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('menuFlyout');
    });
});
```

Comment: @Daniel, I recommend replacing `document` with the parent element to limit the scope of `on()`.

Comment: Thanks guys but neither helps! I see what's happening, or trying to happen but now the class is not even changing for the first click. Would there be any difference between
 `addClass('closeFlyout').removeClass('menuFlyout')` and `.attr('class','menuFlyout')`
?

Comment: @Daniel: sorry, there was a mispelling error on my code. Just fixed it, please try it again.

Answer (score 2):

check the class name whether have you spelled correctly. check in firebug as well. 
try as follows to see whether it works:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.menuFlyout').live('click',function(){
        jQuery('.menuFlyout').addClass('closeFlyout');
        jQuery('.menuFlyout').removeClass('menuFlyout');
    });
    jQuery('.closeFlyout').live('click',function(){
        jQuery('.closeFlyout').addClass('menuFlyout');
        jQuery('.closeFlyout').removeClass('closeFlyout');
    });
});
```

Hope this helps, thanks